# Multiple Master => SIngle Slave replication on MySQL

Tags: mysql

I want to make a dedicated SLAVE machine for data replication of three database on three different servers. In other words, I want to do Multiple Master => SIngle Slave replication.

Is there any way to do this, as simple as it can be ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is possible to only replicate certain databases, however that gives you problem if you are doing cross-database updates which would break on the slave in that case.

See here: https://serverfault.com/questions/405096/mysql-per-database-replication

Also, this is the same question:

[Single slave - multiple master MySQL replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7544241/single-slave-multiple-master-mysql-replication)

Answer (score 0):

You can take help from here but need to test first at your own:

http://www.fromdual.com/sites/default/files/mm-single-slave-repl.pdf